# create new column to store quarter of year from existing datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has datetime column: `DateOfDisc`.

I need to write a query that will create dynamic new column that will show the quarter of `DateOfDisc` in that format: "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", hence:

> if Month(`DateOfDisc`) is 1 or 2 or 3 than value will be Q1 
>   if
>   Month(`DateOfDisc`) is 4 or 5 or 6 than value will be Q2  
>   if
>   Month(`DateOfDisc`) is 7 or 8 or 9 than value will be Q3 
>   if
>   Month(`DateOfDisc`) is 10 or 11 or 12 than value will be Q4

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Add a computed column, to make sure data is consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use [**DATEPART()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174420.aspx) function with Quarter option to fetch Quarter to which date belongs

```
SELECT *, 'Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, DateOfDisc) AS VARCHAR(1)) as Quarter
FROM TableName
```

Comment: thank you very much everybody for your help. i will use that, because it uses internal function (datepart) and its less code.

Comment: Never use `char()`, `varchar()`, `nchar()`, or `nvarchar()` without a length specifier in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and can result in a very hard-to-find error.

Comment: It can be done shorter without cast and with less computation power

Comment: @ChristianMICHON - If you write that query without a `CAST` you're trying to concatenate an integer to a character, which forces an implicit conversion using data-type order of precedence.  In short, your code is shorter, slightly more ambiguous, but yields the same plan and uses the same `computation power`.  As a general rule; you *should* include a `CAST` or `CONVERT` to make your code explicit and robust *(because not typing it does Not save any 'computation power')*.

Comment: @MatBailie isn't calling datepart() more compute intensive than integer division?

Comment: @ChristianMICHON - Your answer *(with integer division)* uses `MONTH()`.  The cost of `DATEPART()` and `MONTH()` are the same.  *(As is the cost of `DATENAME()` which also avoids the need to convert from integer to character.)*

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is the standard definition for quarter, so the simplest method is to use `datename()`, because this returns a string not a number:

```
SELECT 'Q' + DATENAME(QUARTER, DateOfDisc) as Quarter
```

If you want, you can make this a computed column so it is available to anyone who uses the table:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD Quarter as ('Q' + DATENAME(QUARTER, DateOfDisc));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a computed column, to make sure data always is consistent:

```
alter table tablename
    add q as case when Month(DateOfDisc) in (1,2,3) then 'Q1'
                  when Month(DateOfDisc) in (4,5,6) then 'Q2'
                  when Month(DateOfDisc) in (7,8,9) then 'Q3'
                  when Month(DateOfDisc) in (10,11,12) then 'Q4'
             end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM, Edate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q1'
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, Edate) BETWEEN 3 AND 6 THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, Edate) BETWEEN 6 AND 9 THEN 'Q3' 
    ELSE 'Q4'
    END
FROM #TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATEPART. See example:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, M, '2016-01-01') SomeDate
    FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) T(M)
)
SELECT SomeDate, 'Q'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(QUARTER, SomeDate)) [Quarter]
FROM Src
```

It yields:

```
SomeDate                  Quarter
-----------------------   -------
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000   Q1
2016-02-01 00:00:00.000   Q1
2016-03-01 00:00:00.000   Q1
2016-04-01 00:00:00.000   Q2
2016-05-01 00:00:00.000   Q2
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000   Q2
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000   Q3
2016-08-01 00:00:00.000   Q3
2016-09-01 00:00:00.000   Q3
2016-10-01 00:00:00.000   Q4
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000   Q4
2016-12-01 00:00:00.000   Q4
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a computed column without case, using a simple division.

```
alter table tablename add quarter as 'Q'||(2+Month(DateOfDisc))/3
```

If casting is a concern of yours:

```
alter table tablename add quarter as 'Q'||cast((2+Month(DateOfDisc))/3 as varchar(1))
```

Comment: That will give quarters `0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4` due to integer division.

Comment: @MatBailie indeed. Edited and corrected. I tested with today's date.

Comment: Or just use `DATENAME(QUARTER, DateOfDisc)` and then you can avoid the `2+`, the `/3` and the `CAST`...

Comment: Datename() is not portable to all SQL platforms. I tried to give a generic answer, working on most SQL flavors. I did not notice the sql-server tag, I thought this was a pure generic SQL question

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this table of revenue and you want to get the 4-quarters division

```
date       | revenue | division
-----------|---------|---------
2018-01-20 | 1500000 | chemo
2019-02-21 | 1200000 | agri
2019-04-09 | 390900  | pharma
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE revn 
(
  date  DATE,
  rev  INTEGER,
  division TEXT
);


INSERT INTO revn (date, rev, division)
VALUES
    ("2018-01-20", 1500000, "D1"),
    ("2019-02-21", 1200000, "d2"),
    ("2019-04-09", 390900, "d3")
    ("2019-04-09", 390900, "d4");
```

There are function called `QUARTER(col_name)` , [please see the w3school docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_quarter.asp), which will come in handy in this case like the following:

```sql
SELECT (
  SELECT QUARTER(date) 
) AS q, rev
FROM revn;
```

The output should be:

```sql
**[Results][2]**:

    | q |     rev |
    |---|---------|
    | 1 | 1500000 |
    | 1 | 1200000 |
    | 2 |  390900 |
    | 2 |  390900 |
```